# Como salvar um gráfico rpart.plot?

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning

Estou trabalhando com decision tree e ao final tenho o gráfico que o representa. Contudo, como se trata de um objeto diferente de outros plots da família ggplot ou ggpubr, não estou conseguindo salvar pelo script. A solução tem sido pelo botão Export/Save Image.

Essa solução limita algumas coisas, dentre elas a automação do processo. Qual a saída para esse problema?

```
# Exemplo para geração do plot

require(rpart.plot) 
binary.model <- rpart(survived ~ ., data = ptitanic, cp = .02)

rpart.plot(binary.model,
           main = "titanic survived\n(binary response)")

rpart.plot(binary.model, type = 3, clip.right.labs = FALSE,
           branch = .4,
           box.palette = "Grays",       # override default GnBu palette
           main = "type = 3, clip.right.labs = FALSE, ...\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `R` possui uma série de comandos para salvar figuras nos formatos bmp, jpeg, png, tiff e pdf. Abaixo coloco um exemplo de como criar um gráfico no formato png utilizando um destes comandos.

```
png("arquivo.png")
rpart.plot(binary.model, type = 3, clip.right.labs = FALSE,
           branch = .4,
           box.palette = "Grays",       # override default GnBu palette
           main = "type = 3, clip.right.labs = FALSE, ...\n")
dev.off()
```

Experimente com os argumentos da função que salva a imagem no formato desejado para que seja possível configurar a resolução da imagem de acordo com a tua necessidade.

Comment: Ok! Resolver a parte de salvar. Contudo, apenas foi para o diretório. Ou seja, não deu para controlar, por exemplo a largura, nem altura, bem como o scale para a resolução da imagem. Procedimentos que são fáceis nos gráficos ggplot com o ggsave().